# copy sematics for callable objects involving "this" pointer

Tags: c++, this, copy-assignment, callable-object

I have a class member which is of type `std::function` that binds to `this` pointer by using `std::bind`.

I implemented assignment operator which must also copy the callable object, however issue is in that, which `this` should be copied? this `this` or other `this`?

Here is sample compileable code to demonstrate:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using func = std::function<void()>;

struct A
{
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "---destructor: " << this << std::endl;
        other_callable();
        this_callable();
    }

    A(const char* name) :
        mName(name)
    {
        other_callable = std::bind(&A::f, this);
        this_callable = std::bind(&A::f, this);
    }

    A& operator=(const A& ref)
    {
        if (this != &ref)
        {
            other_callable = ref.other_callable;
            this_callable = std::bind(&A::f, this);

            mName = ref.mName;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    void f()
    {
        std::cout << mName << ": " << this << std::endl;
    }

    func other_callable;
    func this_callable;
    const char* mName;
};

int main()
{
    A a("a");
    A b("b");

    a.other_callable();
    b.this_callable();
    std::cout << "-------------------" << std::endl;

    a = b;
}
```

Following is non unique sample output:

```
a: 00000090447FF3E0
b: 00000090447FF490
-------------------
---destructor: 00000090447FF490
b: 00000090447FF490
b: 00000090447FF490
---destructor: 00000090447FF3E0
b: 00000090447FF490
b: 00000090447FF3E0
```

As you can see non expected callable object is called in second instance.

What is the problem?

Problem is with `this` pointer that is stored inside the callable object, copying the callable also copies the `this` pointer which means `this` is no longer `this` but rather "other this".

To understand my issue, **the callable object is an event callback** that is being called from external code which assumes that callable will execute on `this` instance but it doesnt, it executes on other instance that was copied.

My question is what would be the correct way to implement copy semantics here?
Right now I favor the `this_callable` version rather than `other_callable` because it referrs to this `this` rather than other `this`.

But I'm not sure whether this is good or bad beyond that it works as expected, while simply copying the callable (other_callable) causes bugs in my code not easy to explain beyond this example.

Is my design with `this_callable` acceptable or should I use `other_callable` for copy sematics and change design elsewhere?

Comment: Have you considered making `this_callable` not capture `this` but instead having a `A*` pointer parameter to which you pass `this` whenever the function is eventually called? It isn't clear to me what the purpose of capturing `this` is.

Comment: If I understand you, that's exactly what I'm doing with `this_callable` because it's the only place where I need to ensure that `this` means `this`, however it results in more callable objects overall, because doing so each instance has it's own callable.

Comment: You forgot to consider the case where `ref`'s callable is some other function than `f`.

Comment: Good point, but I didn't consider that because I know all callables are referring to `A::f`, the callable is never assigned to function that is not `A::f`